# Data Structure to Solution

Tags: metadata, relationships, metadata-relationship

**Current State**

On Account object, there is a record type Supplier. On the Supplier record are 5 checkboxes . Each of these checkboxes indicate a Product. A supplier may sell a product to an consumer or to  a business .

A Supplier may sell 1 or many products.

**What am I trying to achieve ?**

My task is to design a solution such that, the end user can identify which products are sold by a Supplier and to which type of customers i.e to consumer or to Business.

**e.g.**

```
Account Name =The best Supplier in Town 
RecordType = Supplier
Checkbox_ProductA__c = True 
Checkbox_ParoductB__c = True 
Checkbox_ParductC__c = False 
Checkbox_ParductD__c = False 
Checkbox_ParductE__c = True
```

Since `Checkbox_ProductA__c = True`, this means the supplier 'The best Supplier in Town' is authorized to sell ProductA. What would be the best way to indicate if this product is sold by the supplier to both a consumer as well as a Business?

Similarly, since `Checkbox_ProductE__c = True`, this means the supplier 'The best Supplier in Town' is authorized to sell ProductE. what would be the best way to indicate if this product is sold by the supplier to both a consumer as well as a Business?

**Approach 1:** Ideally I would want to create a new object and create a lookup relationship between Supplier Account and the new object.

**Approach 2** Since the business already has check boxes for each of the 5 products, I am thinking of  creating a bunch of Check boxes. e.g

```
If (Checkbox_ProductA__c = True) {

   // display checkbox ProductA__Soldto_Consumer__c

  //  display checkbox ProductA__Soldto_Business__c

} 

If (Checkbox_ProductB__c = True) {

   // display checkbox ProductB__Soldto_Consumer__c

  //  display checkbox ProductB__Soldto_Business__c

}
```

and so on..

**My question**

Can someone please give me some insight into the best way to solution for the task. ?

Comment: The checkboxes themselves **are** the indication of whether or not a supplier can sell a product. Where are you stuck specifically? Is this for lwc? Vfpage?

Comment: Thanks @MarkPond.  You are right the check boxes are an  indication if the supplier can /cannot sell a product. Where i need guidance is, if they do sell a product, I want to indicate if they sell to a business  or to a consumer or both. What i am asking  is, for each of the five products if i create 2 check boxes is that a good approach. e.g. SellsProductA = true , SellstoBusiness = true, SellstoConsumer = False
This is not VFP, or LWC, this is a Standard Account Record Page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with Approach 1 i.e created a 'new Object' with a master detail relationship to Account. On the Parent Account Detail page, created a related list to display records of 'New object'.  This approach offers scalability and robust reporting capabilities.